# Model "File" is missing from the (plugin - upload) models - strapi with cloudinary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi, cloudinary

my strapi app can't start properly. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: The model `File`, used in the attribute `Image` in the model Portfolio-card, is missing from the (plugin - upload) models
```

I think I have all my config files configurated as in the docs. I'm using MongoDB for database. It is connected with the `strapi-connector-mongoose`. The app isn't starting.

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "czarogrod-backend-strapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "strapi": "3.6.11",
    "strapi-admin": "3.3.4",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.3.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.1.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.1.3",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.1.3",
    "strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.1.3",
    "strapi-utils": "3.1.3",
    "video-react": "0.16.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "2474ae8d-dfcf-46d2-9167-e53366ff5737"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.x",
    "npm": "^6.x"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Here's `config/plugins.js`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "cloudinary",
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
        api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
        api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here's `config/middlewares.js`:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "res.cloudinary.com",
          ],
          "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "res.cloudinary.com",
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Here's `extensions/upload/config.js`:

```js
{
  "provider": "cloudinary",
  "providerOptions": {
    "cloud_name": "###",
    "api_key": "###",
    "api_secret": "###"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The [Cloudinary package has to be installed](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration) as the 3rd-party tools would need to use it (e.g., strapi) - `npm install cloudinary`

Comment: @epasos_573 I installed it but the error is still showing up. I also tried deleting `node-modules` and reinstalling them but it didn't help either. My `package.json` now says: `"cloudinary": "^1.32.0",`